# Connect MacBook Pro to Smart TV wirelessly

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, television, chromecast

I have a MacBook Pro running High Sierra 10.13.6.

In my house I have two Smart TVs:

- LG Smart TV with webOS
- Xiaomi Mi SmartTV with Android TV 9.0

I would like to wirelessly transmit the screen of my MacBook to these TVs (not both at the same time because they are in different house's divisions).

I know that Xiaomi Mi SmartTV has Chromecast incorporated but I think that would only work with Google Chrome's "cast" feature.

I want to transmit the screen of my MacBook to these TVs so I can work in different apps, documents, code and watch movies.

Is there any way to do this without Apple TV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Google Chrome installed, open it.
Then click the three lines in the top right corner then Cast -> Sources -> Desktop -> [chromecast name] TV

Make sure Google Chrome has screen recording permissions in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy

I don't know if this is what you were mentioning in your first post, but this is what works best for me.  I think in your post you were mentioning casting just the tab you are looking at, whereas my method casts the entire display.

Comment: But I think that method will only cast Google Chrome tabs, right? I was looking to cast the full screen so I could work in other APPs/Docs.

Comment: If when you are casting you click "Sources" then "Cast Desktop" it will cast the entire screen.

Comment: Or if you are willing to pay $10, [this app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/screen-mirror-to-tv-device/id1496988766?mt=12) works really well.  Make sure it works for you with the trial before you buy it though.

Comment: It worked! However it's not possible to set my TV as a second screen where I can drag stuff isn't it?

Comment: Yeah you won’t be able to do that, sorry!  But if this answers your question, make sure to mark it as the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to transmit the screen of my MacBook to these TVs so I can work in different apps, documents, code and watch movies.

You need a simple [AirPlay compatible dongle](http://radnex.us/AirPlay_Dongles_Miracast-DNLA) plugged into the HDMI port of your TV.

I have used several of these in different locations

- The work great for business presentations (i.e. PowerPoint) and simple animations
- They work fairly well for playing standard definition video (i.e. YouTube or regular DVD).
- It's marginal at best once you get to HD video (720p or 1080p)
- If you want 4K, UHD, HDR, etc, you need an AppleTV.
- It **doesn't** get around any copy protected (DRM) content; it won't play!

For their price point of sub $50 USD, they're a great little adapters to keep in your computer bag for when you go on client site for a presentation, training, or you just want to mirror to a larger screen.  It's also good to attach to a projector so guests can easily connect.  They're convenient, but not meant for high performance so keep that in mind when putting together your solution.

Comment: But is there any way to do this without any external dongle?

Comment: I haven’t found any software I’d  be willing to use, if that’s what you’re asking.

Comment: Yeap, that's what I was asking for. I did a search before asking here and didn't find it either.